# A plot cannot rendered when using 2 different datasets in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I made a simple shiny apps with using two datasets. The result of the apps are two:

1. Pie chart with the [first dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16jK7gsa69J1pFShxMp5FBbeKfkYs-7wq/view?usp=sharing)
2. bar chart with the [second dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JjogC5MpQC53ciKJ79fDuBBOQHQ2ABgK/view?usp=sharing).

However when I ran the code, the shiny apps only display the bar chart. Here is the picture of the [pie chart](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r6ZanNFO-FL2NRb8jvjCrYW8z2M9dwu2/view?usp=drive_link), and here is the picture of the [bar chart](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i37SB-W73iuOcwMw61_XNDHjWD_r85Tc/view?usp=sharing).

I am using this code, I believe that I made a mistake when using the `reactive` function. How I can render both charts? Thank you very much.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Baseline data statistics for Perfect Fit"),
    
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Workshop Attendance",
               sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(selectInput("age_cat", 
                           label = "Select age category that apply",
                           choices = unique(df_pie$age_cat),
                           )),
               
               mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "piePlot")))
               ),
      
      tabPanel("Menstruation Knowledge",
               sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(selectInput("age_cat1",
                            label = "Select age category that apply",
                            choices = unique(df_bar$age_cat)
                           ),
               selectInput("question_cat",
                           label = "Select menstrual topic that apply",
                           choices = unique(df_bar$statement_cat)
                           )),
               mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "barPlot"))
               )
      )
    )
)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  plot1 <- reactive({
    req(input$age_cat)
    df_pie %>% 
      distinct(no, .keep_all = T) %>%
      filter(age_cat == input$age_cat) %>% ## Input variable
      group_by(`Workshop participation`) %>% 
      summarise(Percentage=n()/nrow(.)) %>%
      mutate(ymax = cumsum(Percentage),
             ymin = c(0, ymax[1]),
             label = (ymax + ymin)/2, 
             lab = paste0(round(Percentage * 100, 1), '% ', `Workshop participation`))
  })
  
  plot2 <- reactive({
    req(input$age_cat1,
        input$question_cat)
    df_bar %>%
      filter(age_cat == input$age_cat1) %>% ## Input Variable
      filter(statement_cat == input$question_cat) %>% ## Input variable
      na.omit() %>%
      count(statement, answer) %>%
      mutate(percentage = n/(n[1] + n[2])) %>%
      filter(answer == "Correct") 
  })

    output$piePlot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(plot1(), aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3, fill=`Workshop participation`)) +
        labs(title = paste0("Workshop attendance, ", input$age_cat)) +
        geom_rect() +
        coord_polar(theta="y") +
        xlim(c(1, 4)) + 
        theme_void() +
        scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FF9900", "#A7A9AC")) +
        geom_text(x = 2, aes(y = label, label = lab), color = "#000000", family = "Proxima Nova Rg", size = 5) +
        theme(legend.position = "none",
              plot.title = element_text(family = "Proxima Nova Rg", size = 20, color = "#000000"))
      
      output$barPlot <- renderPlot({

          ggplot(plot2(), aes(x = statement, y = percentage, fill = percentage)) +
          geom_col(width = 0.7) +
          labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL, title = paste0("Menstrual practices knowledge score, ", input$age_cat1)) +
          geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(percentage*100, 1), "%")), vjust = -0.5, family = "Proxima Nova Rg", size = 5) +
          theme_minimal() +
          scale_fill_gradient(low = "#FFE0B1", high = "#FF9900") +
          scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1),
                             expand = c(0,0)) +
          theme(legend.position = "none",
                axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                axis.text.x = element_text(family = "Proxima Nova Rg", size = 8.9, color = "#000000"),
                panel.grid.major =element_blank(),
                axis.line.x = element_line(size = 0.5),
                plot.title = element_text(family = "Proxima Nova Rg", size = 18, color = "#000000", hjust = 0.5))
      })
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You have put `output$barPlot` inside the first `renderPlot` `output$piePlot`.